# CausalImpact package - results summary inconsistent with the result plots

Tags: python, causality, causalimpact

I'm trying to get some experience with the `CausalImpact` [package][1] in python.

I'm using this seemingly simple example:

```
import pandas as pd
from causalimpact import CausalImpact

# treatment data
t = np.array([2.]*180+[4.]*60)
t+= np.random.normal(scale=0.15, size=240)      # adding some noise

# control 1
c1 = np.array([1.]*240)
c1 += np.random.normal(scale=0.15, size=240)    # adding some noise

# control 2
c2 = np.array([3.]*240)
c2 += np.random.normal(scale=0.15, size=240)    # adding some noise

# make into a df
df = pd.DataFrame({'treatment':t, 'control1':c1, 'control2':c2})

pre_period = [0,179]
post_period = [180, 239]

# instantiate and fit/train a model
ci = CausalImpact(dead_simple_df, pre_period, post_period)
ci.run()
```

Essentially, what the data shows:

- in the pre-treatment period:

  - the would-be-treated group has an average of 2.
  - one control would have an average of 1, and the other and average of 3.
  - hence, a simple model that's a 50-50 average of the controls would predict the would-be-treated group very well.
- in the post-treatment period:

  - the treated group see a flat increase of 2 units
  - nothing else changes

When I call `ci.plot()` the plot shows this pre-treatment average of 2 and post-treatment average of 4 very nicely.

[image: plot]

However, when I call `ci.summary(output='report')` the summary says the impact is 1.
Further:

> *During the post-intervention period, the response variable had an average value of approx. 3*
> [image]

Any idea what might be going on?

TIA!